# Using forEach to hide buttons and show others

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach, display

how can I use forEach to show a button or hide it when i click on a button?

say we have 3 buttons, and currently showing only 2, and whichever one you click on will hide one and show the other (as shown in the snippet). It works fine here but i want the process to continue that way when i click on one of the buttons again, especially if you have a long list, and it doesn't have to hide only one button, maybe hide both of them and show 2 different ones (if you have more than 3 elements in your list)

```js
let characters = [
   {name: document.getElementById("name1").textContent, points: 0},
   {name: document.getElementById("name2").textContent, points: 0},
   {name: document.getElementById("name3").textContent, points: 0}
   ]
   
function choice (button) {
   const buttonCharacterObject = characters.find(obj => obj.name === button.textContent);
   buttonCharacterObject.points += 1;
   const ranking = characters.sort((a, b) => (a.points < b.points ? 1 : -1));
   console.log(ranking);
   document.getElementById('name2').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('name3').style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
.btn {
    display: none;
}

#name1 {
    display: inline;
}

#name2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="name1" onclick="choice(this)">Martin</button>
<button class="btn" id="name2" onclick="choice(this)">Sam</button>
<button class="btn" id="name3" onclick="choice(this)">John</button>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want when there are more buttons?

Comment: for example i have 5 buttons named: Mark, John, Sam, Martin, James. and I'm displaying only 2 of them (Mark & John for example), I want to hide that pair when I click on any of the buttons and display another pair, it doesn't need to have one of the previous names, for example: Martin & James, and repeat that process until i've gone  through all of the pairs